# SQL Server order by expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

While watching Troy Hunt's fantastic [course on  SQLi](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/ethical-hacking-sql-injection), I've noticed that he ends up using this strategy to see if a table has a specific column:

```
select * from TableA order by (select top 1 some_column from TableB) desc
```

This expression will get executed by SQL Server, but what will it do for the order by clause? I've seen expressions being used with order by before (case when then else end), but I'm really curious to understand how SQL can process the previous query without any errors...

**EDIT**: Giving more info because it seems like my initial post was not clear enough:

1. I know this is not the best strategy for getting table or column name though SQLi (that's not what I'm asking)
2. I'm not interested in knowing how to protect against this (I know how to do that already)
3. I know that sorting by a constant value doesn't make sense (though it allows you to run these types of "boolean queries")
4. What t  I really want to know is why it works.

So, going back to the docs, the `order by` clause expects an [order_by_expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which is described as:

> Specifies a column or expression on which to sort the query result set. A sort column can be specified as a name or column alias, or a nonnegative integer representing the position of the column in the select list.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), an expression is:

> Is a combination of symbols and operators that the SQL Server Database Engine evaluates to obtain a single data value. Simple expressions can be a single constant, variable, column, or scalar function. Operators can be used to join two or more simple expressions into a complex expression.

As @SMor demonstrated, the query does run if you replace the order by select expression with a simple `select 'A'`:

```
select * from TableA order by (select 'A') desc
```

But this does not work:

```
select * from TableA order by 'A' desc
```

So, the question is: why is `select 'A'` accepted by SQL Server in the order by clause? Doesn't it produce a constant too? Since a constant is an expression and taking into account the definition for the `order by` clause, shouldn't it thrown an error in both cases?

Thanks.

Comment: "this strategy to see if a table has a specific column" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: This is used as an example of injection that answers yes or no. If there's no table or if there's no column, an exception will get thrown (this is useful when sql exception aren't propagated to the client). When tje column and table do exist, sql returns records, though im not sure how they're ordered...you can test this on ssms and aee that the query does get executed (even when the order by select returns a string...

Comment: Looks like a pretty bad strategy: what happens if the column is called `1); drop TableA; --`, it's still going to cause injection. The only way to protect against injection is to not have injection in the first place. In other words, you should always be in full control of SQL, and if dynamic SQL is necessary the use DMVs such as `sys.columns` and `sys.tables` to build up the query

Comment: Again, it's not what I asking... What i really want to know is why does the query run without any error and what does it use for sorting. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't use anything for sorting. It recognizes during the optimisation process that it is actually a constant and it gets optimised out. The "constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list" is quite conservative and only happens in quite simple cases. The `ORDER BY (SELECT ...)` is quite useful sometimes. e.g. in conjunction with `ROW_NUMBER` to give each row a unique number in any order without requiring a sort]

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith...would you mind giving a concrete example where the oder by (select) approach is useful? thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `(select top 1 some_column from TableB)` is an example of a *scalar subquery*.  This is a subquery that returns exactly one column and at most one row.  It can be used anywhere a literal value can be used -- and perhaps in some other places as well.  Apparently, it can be used in an `order by`, even though SQL Server does not allow a literal value for `order by`.

The most common type of scalar subquery is a *correlated subquery*, which has a `where` clause that connects the subquery to the outer query.  This is not an example of a scalar subquery.

In fact, this is not an example of anything useful as far as I can tell.  It has one major shortcoming, which is the use of `top` without `order by`.  The value returned by the subquery is indeterminate.  That seems like a bad practice, and particularly bad if you are trying to teach people SQL.

And, it is probably going to be evaluated once.  So the subquery would return a constant value and would not contribute much to a meaningful ordering.

Comment: Sure, so it produces a constant... Ok, then try replacing the select with a constant string expression (ex: 'a') and let me know what happens...

Comment: @LuisAbreu Um, why does anyone need to do that and tell you what happens? It generates an error (depending on how you encode the constant) because it is logical nonsense to order by a literal. Your source uses a query that is logically the same as ordering by a constant but does not throw an error. You could also include a constant in the select list and order by it - same logical nonsense. [fiddle to demonstrate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=feb3997b9c4666813bf3593d6f559a10). Is there a point?

Comment: I'm not saying it makes sense, jus trying to understand the rationale behind it. Why does it run with select but not with a constant? Aren't those examples of expressions?

Comment: @LuisAbreu . . . You have to ask Microsoft.  It also works I think if you put in a `case` expression that always evaluates to the same thing.

Comment: Hello @GordonLinoff. Well, since I don't know anyone at MS, I thought this would be a good place to ask. Regarding case, not sure on what you mean...